# Is it possible to create an EMF object programmatically?

Tags: java, emf

I need to create a dynamic EMF object just by coding in java. Is it possible ?
If so, please explain me with a code snippet on how to create an EMF object.

Comment: You probably won't get any help with on this question. I'm going to downvote for now. What we need to see from you is code showing *what you have tried* and code showing *where you're having trouble*. You might want to take a look at this post on how to ask a question at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

To create eObject programmatically, just use `EcoreUtil` and `EcoreFactory` like this:

```
EClass eClass = EcoreFactory.eINSTANCE.createEClass();
eClass.setName("DEMO");
eClass.setInterface(true);
EObject obj = EcoreUtil.create(eClass);
```